# AngularJS best practices

Tags: angularjs

I have a large angularjs application.  It is structured in a module pattern like:

```
./
 /search
   search.js
 /admin
   /users
       users.js
   /settings
       settings.js
   admin.js
/edit
   edit.js
/common
   /components
       /modal
           modal.js
   /services
       auth.js
```

and so on.  currently they are all under one angularjs 'module' e.g.:

```
var app = var app = angular.module('myapp', []);
```

and then in subsequent controllers/etc I do

```
app.controller('SearchCtrl', function(){ ... })
```

but as I look around the web at examples such as [Angular CRUD Demo](https://github.com/angular-app/angular-app) and [ngBolierplate](https://github.com/ngbp/ngbp) I find most of them split up each nested module(s) into their own 'module' rather than just strap it onto the main one.

Whats the best practice here?  I've seen both but not sure which is the 'angular way'.

Comment: I wondered the same about here is some helpful info [Angular Best Practices](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20802798/1959948)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taken from [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1XXMvReO8-Awi1EZXAXS4PzDzdNvV6pGcuaF4Q9821Es/pub), which was linked to on the [official angular blog](http://blog.angularjs.org/2014/02/an-angularjs-style-guide-and-best.html) and referred to as best practice (emphasis mine):

> Module definitions
>
> In general, 'angular.module('foo')' should be called only once. Other modules and files can depend on it, **but they should never modify it**.
> Module definition can happen in the main module file, or in subdirectories for sections or components, depending on the application's needs.

So, I think the preferred method is to have each `.js` file declaring its own module, then referencing those modules in the main `app.js` file in the root of the project.

Comment: Interesting ... thanks for the input ... it's hard to find relevant large scale examples

Comment: Yes it is. It's something I'm still trying to get right to be honest!