# Using AngularJS in local HTML

Tags: angularjs, local

What are the best practices for using AngularJS in local HTML? By that, I mean HTML files opened directly from the local file system, not from a web server.

I have had some luck in replacing partials that are in separate files with partials within script tags. And replacing Ajax calls with including JS files that contain the JSON data. However, I wondered if there are any guidelines for doing this, or even helper libraries?

BTW, my use case is a desktop application that generates HTML reports that are server using a local web server. In some cases users want to create a ZIP file that contains an HTML report, which they can email to someone else. Given the sensitivity of these reports, people may have objections to using a cloud service. Having HTML in a zip file gives them control of their data.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20802798/1959948