# Partial html and the Angular team new best practice file structure

Tags: angularjs

This [blog post](http://blog.angularjs.org/2014/02/an-angularjs-style-guide-and-best.html) from the Angular team has a [new recommendation](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1XXMvReO8-Awi1EZXAXS4PzDzdNvV6pGcuaF4Q9821Es/pub) for app file structure.

But I do not quite understand where to put my html-partial. Take this example: I have a partial that is the html for entering and confirming a password. I use this both under signup-page and under change-password-page.

So I have this file structure:

```
user/signup/signup.html
user/signup/signup-controller.ja
user/change-password/change-password.html
user/change-password/change-password-controller.ja
```

But where would the recommended place to put my small piece of partial-html, my file:
`password-and-confirm-input-fields.html`? It does not have a controller or anything such...

Comment: which feature does it belong to? Think of each folder as a feature, not a controller dependent space. If the file is login form, maybe it will fit right into user/login or /login for that matter. The important part is the splitting of folders, so you do not end up with folder structure like "model,view,controler" or "Services, Factories, Partials" or etc..

Comment: btw if its "global" it goes in the components and in an approriate named folder.

Comment: Check this long set of recommendations for [angular app structures](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20802798/1959948)

Comment: Ronny, in my example case, the password-and-confirm-partial, belongs to two features, the signup-feature and the change-password-feature. Does this make it global? They are both user-related features and my partial would not be used elsewhere...