# AngularJS : how to organize your code?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm currently trying to get all the concepts that AngularJS involves and it's pretty big. I understood most of it but I still don't really get how to organize your app.

Let's take this example : on the homepage, I have a few blocks : each of thems are simply tabbed content (example : the 1st has 2 links, Posts / Articles, each render inside of the block either lasts Posts or lasts Articles depending on link clicked, the 2nd Music / Video, same thing for rendered content, etc...). How should I organize this in the best way possible ?

Thank you for the help :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Angularjs code/naming conventions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20802798/angularjs-code-naming-conventions)

Comment: Just read it. It probably answers my question but it's hard to globalize everything when starting with Angular. That's why I ask this question about a specific example

Answer (score 1):

[image: project layour]

As this is subjective question, I can only show you how we organized our application. Works very well and stuff is easy to find. It is divided by functional area.

Comment: Thanks for the help but that doesn't clarify much for me :/ I'm trying to set up a little bit of code to make a clearer question