# what is the recommended way to submit a form with angular js

Tags: angularjs

What is the recommended way to submit a form with angularjs. Will all the different form fields be automatically turned into JSON?

Comment: [Angular Best Practices](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20802798/1959948)

Comment: -1 already? I don't see why you guys have to try to make technology  inaccessible to lay people, unless you realize your job is so easy that you have to protect it through artificial means.

Answer (score 0):

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div ng-app='mymodule' ng-controller="PeopleController as pc">
<form name="myform" ng-submit="pc.submit(person)">
<input  ng-model="person.name"/>
<input  ng-model="person.age"/>
<input type="submit" />
</form>
</div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-rc.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
(function (){
 angular.module('mymodule',[])
 .controller('PeopleController',function($scope,$http) {
   $scope.person={'name':'john'};
   this.submit = function(p){$http.post('/path/to/my.php',p).success(function(e){console.log(e);});};
 });
})();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```