# Angular seed with services and directives

Tags: angularjs

I am using angular seed project
    https://github.com/angular/angular-seed

where should I put the services and directives ?

Comment: [Angular Best Practices](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20802798/1959948)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really totally up to you but there are some good recommendations on project structure here: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1XXMvReO8-Awi1EZXAXS4PzDzdNvV6pGcuaF4Q9821Es/pub

Typically my structure looks something like

```
app\scripts\user.js
app\scripts\todo.js
```

Where User.js would have a service and possibly multiple controllers in it... if the file gets too large then I break it up into parts.

The problem with grouping all services together and all controllers is that the services and controllers typically have a relationship (functionally).  When you want to re-use the service/controller you are typically going to use them together, when editing one you usually need a reference to the other.  This makes it easiest to find things and not have 1000 js files to include and manage in the dependencies and script inclusions.

Also when it comes time and you want to make a bower component out of one of the sections it's easier to see which parts need to be pulled out.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a folder for each under `app`, so your project tree will look like this:

```
app/directives
app/services
```